# Windows / Linux SQLAlchemy connector Conversion type Error

Tags: python, mysql, linux, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

I've been working in a project that uses SQLAlchemy to work with a MySQL database. I've done all the tests in my Windows machine. The problem had come when I moved the project to the Ubuntu server 20.04. There I got the following error:  `Python 'float64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type`. Doing some research I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667627/python-float64-cannot-be-converted-to-a-mysql-type-but-in-manual-query-thats-n) similar case. The suggestion is just to use `int()` or `float()` to convert numbers explicitly. But a question still remains: Why should it work on windows and not on Linux?

Doing more research I've found that it is probably a problem of the connector, which it is not the same in Windows and Linux. Actually I had some previous problems because in Windows I instantiate the engine: `db_config = 'mysql://{}:{}@localhost/{}?charset=utf8mb4'.format(db_user, db_pass, db_schema)`, this is, only specifying the dialect and not the connector. While in Linux, only work if I specify both: `db_config = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@localhost/{}?charset=utf8mb4'.format(db_user, db_pass, db_schema)`

On Windows I'm using the connector `PyMySQL` with `Xampp 7.1.9` and DB `10.1.26-MariaDB` with the engine `InnoDB`. On Linux I use the connector `mysqlconnector` with the server MySQL `8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3` and also the engine `InnoDB`. It is worth to mention that I only have troubles when a `float64` is written on the DB.

So, after this long introduction (sorry for it) the specific questions are:

1. Is it, actually, a problem of the connector? Or I'm missing something here?
2. Is there a way to use the same code in Windows than in Linux? (maybe only adding the dialect and the connector on Linux)
3. Should I program everything from now on, specifying the conversion `float()` every-time I write a float into the database?

Any clue to those questions is more than welcome.

Comment: It would help to know which connectors, and versions, you were using on each platform.  And the same for the database engine.

Comment: @snakecharmerb You're totally right there. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @snakecharmerb I reallize that I only need to use the same connector. So everything get solved by using on Linux:  `mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@localhost/{}?charset=utf8mb4'.format(db_user, db_pass, db_schema)`. This is, using the connector `PyMySQL` instead of `mysqlconnector`.