# MySql Python Connector turns INT into int64, but not back again?

Tags: python, mysql, integer, int64

I am using the MySQL Python connector to manipulate a database, but running into issues when my queries involve the INT database type. When MySQL retrieves an INT column from the database, it seems to convert to a Python int64. This is fine, **except it doesn't convert it back** into a usable MySql type.

Here's a reduced example:

This is my MySql schema for table 'test', with Id as datatype INT:
[image]

[image]

My Python code is below. The 2nd execute (an UPDATE query) fails with this exception:

```
Exception Thrown: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'int64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

If I explicitly convert the 'firstId' parameter (which is reported as type <class 'numpy.int64'>), using `int(firstId)`, the code runs successfully: [as per another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667627/python-float64-cannot-be-converted-to-a-mysql-type-but-in-manual-query-thats-n). I would have, perhaps naively, assumed that if MySql managed the conversion in one direction, it would manage it in the other. As it is, I don't necessarily know the types that I am getting from my actual query (I'm using Python ... I shouldn't have to know). Does this mean that I will have to type-check all my Python variables before running MySql queries?

I tried changing the table column datatype from INT to BIGINT (an 64-bit INT), but I got the same conversion error. Is there perhaps a 32-bit / 64-bit mismatch on the MySql connector package I am using (mysql-connector-python 8.0.23)?

```
import mysql.connector as msc
import pandas as pd

def main():
    dbConn = msc.connect(user='********', password='********',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='********')
    #Open a cursor
    cursor = dbConn.cursor()
    #Find Id of given name
    cursor.execute('SELECT * from test WHERE Name = %s',['Hector'])
    headers = cursor.column_names
    queryVals = list()

    for row in cursor:
            queryVals.append(row)
        
    cursor.close()   
    dfQueryResult = pd.DataFrame(queryVals,columns = headers)
    
    print(dfQueryResult)

    #Change name 
    firstId = dfQueryResult['Id'].iloc[0]
    print('firstId is of type: ',type(firstId))

    cursor = dbConn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('UPDATE test SET Name =%s WHERE Id =%s',['Graham',firstId]) #This line gives the error
    print(cursor.rowcount,' rows updated')
        
    cursor.close()   

    dbConn.commit()
    dbConn.close()

main()
```

Comment: i think the issue might be from the guessing of types made by pandas. I could think that if you were not fetching data in pandas but loop through directly from your results, then it wouldn't call that error, but woud need to check.

Comment: check pandas doc, i think you may just want to add dtype to your Dataframe creation:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: @NonoLondon Thanks ... I will take a look and revert!

Comment: @NonoLondon So I tried various dtype settings (dtype=int, dtype=numpy.intc etc) and whichever type I chose, MySql still complained about being unable to convert whatever type it was (numpy.xxx) to int. DataFrames are ubiquitous and seem to be such an obvious container for SQL result sets (eg the DataFrame read_sql() fn), that I am a little surprised that they don't work straight out of the box with the MySQL python connector. I guess I can just put in an intermediate step that looks at the parameters for the update query and converts to python int (using the base numpy int type to check).

Comment: i managed to make it work using dtype=float, counterintuitive and probably prone to errors. Looking at other chats, seems like you are supposed to implement your own class converter. I read as well that django recommends mysql library, rather than this connector, if that something you can do.

Comment: the issue seems to be more on the driver side that doesn't default convert python ints into mysql ints, which has its pros and cons (I would have personaly prefered that the driver auto convert, and let you provide a class when you want to taylor made)

Comment: @NonoLondon Thanks to your investigations, and some other SO answers, I found the NumPy item() method that converts a NumPy type to a Python type, and I added a pyTypeFromNp(val) utility which checks whether val is an instance of the Numpy.generic class, in which case it calls item(). Perhaps I was overly optimistic on the type conversion: it would be hard for the MySql connector to know how its values were being type-converted (unless it fully embraced DataFrames with the attendant dependency issues). If you would like to post your comments as an answer, I will be happy to accept it!

Comment: Maybe just post your answer, seems like it will be a better post than me posting more things.Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, hat-tip to @NonoLondon for their comments and investigative work.

A pandas Dataframe stores numbers using NumPy types. In this case, the DataFrame constructor was taking a Python 'int' from the MySql return and converting it into a Numpy.int64 object. When this variable was used again by MySql, the connector could not convert the Numpy.int64 back to a straight Python 'int'.

From other SO articles, I discovered the item() method for all Numpy data types, which converts into base Python types. Since all Numpy data types are derived from the base class Numpy.generic, I'm now using the following utility function whenever I extract variables from DataFrames:

```
import numpy as np

def pyTypeFromNp(val):
    if isinstance(val,np.generic):
        return val.item()

    return val
```

Hence the amended line is now:

```
firstId = pyTypeFromNp(dfQueryResult['Id'].iloc[0])
```

and the code runs as expected